# Python Spliting Date/Time into Month, Date, Year, Time columns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, date, time

I have a data frame with a "Date/Time" column looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

example = {'Date/Time' : ['4/1/2014 0:11:00', '4/1/2014 0:17:00', '4/1/2014 0:21:00', '4/1/2014 0:28:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

What I want to do is to split the column into 3 different columns (Month, Date, Year, and Time).

I have tried to use regex based on the code that I used for my other similar problem which was to split a column with "gender, email, phone number' into each.

```
# create gender, phone, email columns by splitting leader contact 
df3[['gender','phone','email']]=df3['Contact'].str.extract('\(([A-Z])\)\s?(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\s?(.*)', expand = False)
```

I basically tried to manipulate extract() part. However, it was too hard for me to figure out. I don't mind to use regex or other 'dates/time' packages.

It will be so helpful for my study if anyone can help.

Comment: Convert to `datetime` and get the individual components no need for regex

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime` and then the `.dt` accessor

Answer (score 1):

I will post the most straightforward way to do this

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'])

df['month'], df['day'], df['year'], df['time'] = (
    df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.day, df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.time)


    Date/Time           date                month   day year    time
0   4/1/2014 0:11:00    2014-04-01 00:11:00 4       1   2014    00:11:00
1   4/1/2014 0:17:00    2014-04-01 00:17:00 4       1   2014    00:17:00
2   4/1/2014 0:21:00    2014-04-01 00:21:00 4       1   2014    00:21:00
3   4/1/2014 0:28:00    2014-04-01 00:28:00 4       1   2014    00:28:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(**{ x: getattr(pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time']).dt, x.lower()) for x in ['Month', 'Date', 'Year', 'Time']})

          Date/Time  Month        Date  Year      Time
0  4/1/2014 0:11:00      4  2014-04-01  2014  00:11:00
1  4/1/2014 0:17:00      4  2014-04-01  2014  00:17:00
2  4/1/2014 0:21:00      4  2014-04-01  2014  00:21:00
3  4/1/2014 0:28:00      4  2014-04-01  2014  00:28:00
```